Why do pressure cookers have relatively low wattage?
Most electric pressure cookers are rated at 1000 watts, and the highest I have found is 1400 watts. The Instant Pot Pro 8 quart is one example.
I checked other electric appliances I own and was surprised at how low this is.

induction cooker: 1800 watts
kettle: 1500 watts
electric stovetop: >2000 watts

I often hear the advice to boil water in a kettle before pouring it into a pressure cooker, so it seems well-known that pressure cookers are slower at heating water.
Why did the manufacturers not increase the wattage of electric pressure cookers?

As Ecnerwal said, any answer would have to be a speculation. So the site doesn't take questions of this form.

@rumtscho A person involved in the design of a pressure cooker might be able to answer without speculation, please reopen

even if there were such a person here on the site (which I very much doubt) the voting would still be random (or rather, depending on factors other than actual expertise of the voter). It's really a typical case of question we don't answer.

Once you reach temperature, you need little power to maintain it. For a 1,000 watts electric pot, you need like 50 watts to keep it hot. If the pot is too powerful (say 2,000 watts) it will be difficult to regulate the power.

I'm dubious that this is legitimately answerable here.
I can speculate that if the thing is designed properly there's no particular need for high wattage (due to good insulation retaining heat.) All that a pressure cooker needs to accomplish is to hold the contents at 250°F/121°C (i.e., 15 PSI/1 Bar steam pressure) at most. Some electrics don't even go that high.
And I can speculate that lower wattage might make passing safety testing (as in "the pressure cooker will safely vent rather than blowing up if the switch fails 'on' ") easier.
But I don't have a pressure cooker factory, or a mind-reading device to use on people who do own one.

it probably helps with other safety testing (won't overheat / catch fire / etc).  and reduces the manufacturing costs

I'm guessing you're somewhere in North America where power is around 120 V and house wiring is on 15 A circuits. An 1800 W induction cooker is 1800 W/120 V or 15 A. That means your circuit is already maxed out.  Any additional current draw will trip the breaker to avoid starting a fire in the house wiring.
In places with 220-240 V, kettles can have higher wattage. The average kettle in Britain is between 2000-3000 W, which is still well under 15 A.
Most pressure cooker manufacturers probably expect to share power with other appliances, not to be the only device on a circuit. They'd keep current use acceptably low to avoid tripping the breaker.

I don't know about expecting to be sharing a circuit... I think it's recommended these days that you have a separate run per outlet in kitchens because so many appliances require a lot of power.  (I have an old house, so I can't use my toaster and microwave at the same time... on  opposite walls of my kitchen... but at least I have circuit breakers now instead of fuses)
